# After cmd python manage.py runserver, project is running but some options of admin panel is showing does not exist after clicking on it

Tags: python, django

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/profile/

Django Version: 3.1.14
Python Version: 3.11.5
Installed Applications:
['jazzmin',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'administration',
'teacher',
'student',
'academic',
'employee',
'result',
'address',
 'account',
'attendance']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Envs\school_management_system\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Envs\school_management_system\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "G:\VS Code Files\school_management_system-master\account\views.py", line 7, in profile
    profile = UserProfile.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Envs\school_management_system\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Envs\school_management_system\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 429, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /account/profile/
Exception Value: UserProfile matching query does not exist.
```

I expect to run the project.

Comment: are you sure the user profile for that user actually exists. Django does not create profiles for you so you need to handle it yourself. check [Documentation here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.